# c++ function turns a float value into a NaN when returns

Tags: c++, function, return, nan

I'm having a weird issue with nvidia texture tools (nvtt) library, which I compile to build my own texture converter. Here is the problem, I got a function which always returns a NaN. Here is it:

```
class Filter // a class inside (nvtt library)
{
public:
    ...
    float width() const
    {
        return m_width; // m_width = 3.0 when debug
    }
    ...
private:
    float m_width;
};
```

when I place a break point at return line, I see the value of m_width is 3.0, but the values returned is always NaN:

```
width = filter.width(); // width = NaN
```

Did I do something wrong with compilation setting (code generation or such thing)?

---

Edited:

I found the problem but cannot fix it because it's the problem of the NVTT library or compiler which I'm not so sure. I had to dig in some assembly knowledge to identify this problem. It turns out that the FPU (floating point unit) stack is full when the function exit so that the returned value put in st0 register become NaN. I have no idea why that stack became full, but it might be the problem of compiler since I'm using the newest Visual C++ Express 2013 and didn't have this issue when compiling NVTT library with VC2012.

Comment: My suggestion is to add a debug print statement. I guess the debugger is playing games with you.

Comment: Methinks you could have wrecked your stack in some way.

Comment: This shall not be an offense, but are you sure that you actually executed `width = filter.width();`? If `width` is still uninitialized it might be NaN.

Comment: Are you using function pointers? And casts? That would be a fairly explosive mixture of ingredients.

Comment: The fragment of code you provided is inadequate for someone to see what can be wrong. You have to place a breakpoint at the assignment then hit F11 to go into the function and keep going until you find out where the value is overwritten.

Comment: Forget the width variable. When the debugger stops at return line, the value of m_width is 3.0. When the function exits, I see this in Autos window:
    nv::Filter::width returned -1.#IND0000. 
So this is the problem of the function when it exits. I'm thinking like Ivaylo Strandjev do, maybe debugger is messing with me. I'm using Visual C++ Express 2013.

Comment: I added a printf("%f\n", m_width); before the return statement and got "3.0" on console screen, but the returned value is still a NaN. The Autos window still shows: nv::Filter::width returned -1.#IND0000

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in MSVC 2013. I ran into an extremely similar problem, also using NVTT library with MSVC 2013. I noticed that when I called into the NVTT library, sometimes it would return with 2 extra entries on the FPU stack.

I traced the problem into some code that was converting `float` to `int` in an internal function called `_ftol3_except()`.  Apparently if the `float` is a `NaN` or `Inf`, then the FPU stack gets something pushed and never popped.

For details:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=929834
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806362/vc12-pollutes-the-floating-point-stack-when-casting-infinity-nan-to-unsigned-long

According to the second link, this will be fixed in update 2 for MSVC 2013.